# Changing core.editor in Git Bash using "--add" or "--replace-all"

Tags: git, git-bash, git-config

I think I made an error when configuring my editor in Git.
I try to reconfigure and I get this warning and error

```
warning: core.editor has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.editor.
```

How do I use `--add` or `--replace-all` to change `core.editor` in Git Bash? I'm working with Sublime Text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message suggests the solution. If you read the [git-config man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), you see:

```
git config [<file-option>] [type] --replace-all name value [value_regex]
[...]
   --replace-all
       Default behavior is to replace at most one line. This replaces all lines
       matching the key (and optionally the value_regex).
```

So:

```
git config --replace-all core.editor myeditor
```